# jQuery.appear simply not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone see why this html code doesn’t work.

It should show an alert when the image gets visible and again when it gets  invisible for the user.

It doesn't work with local libraries either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/morr/jquery.appear/master/jquery.appear.js"></script>

<script>
      var intervals = [];
      $("[id^=light]").on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
          alert("appeared");
      });

      $("[id^=light]").on('disappear', function(event, $all_disappeared_elements) {
          alert("disappeared");
      });

          </script>

      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Incandescent_light_bulb.svg/200px-Incandescent_light_bulb.svg.png" align="center" id="LichtStatus" style="height:10vh">

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats... a lot of `<br>` tags, wouldn't css be better?

Comment: There are no elements which match your jQuery selectors, so no `appear` or `disappear` events are being bound.  This JavaScript effectively doesn't do anything when it runs.

Comment: You selector `[id^=light]` can't find this `id="LichtStatus"`... I wonder why... Maybe a typo? ;)

Comment: put in ``$(document).ready();``

Comment: ... and *the reason you need to put it in a DOM ready function* is that your script is loaded & run *before* the DOM elements it references are loaded. You could also put your script at the end of body and it will work too (once you fix the incorrect selector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code inside document ready to make sure the DOM is loaded. Also specify the element as @Louys Patrice Bessette mentioned. I added `appear` call which @Deep got right.

```
 <script>    
 $(function(){
 var intervals = [];
  $("img[id^='Licht']").appear();
  $("img[id^='Licht']").on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
      alert("appeared");
  });

  $("img[id^='Licht']").on('disappear', function(event,$all_disappeared_elements) {
      alert("disappeared");
  });
});
</script>
```

I saw that the alerts show twice with the above code. After I change the code as below, I noticed that the alerts don't show twice.

```
$(document.body).on('appear',"img[id^='Licht']", function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
      alert("appeared");
  });

  $(document.body).on('disappear',"img[id^='Licht']", function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
      alert("disappeared");
  });
```

Comment: Edited and added the detail.

Comment: Still Missing a brace (on the doc ready)... Best to use `$(function(){_your DOM ready code here_});` anyway

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: It's `id^Licht` not `id^light`. Looks like something got lost in the OPs translation (literally) :)

Comment: It works thanks, any idea why it triggers twice hen scrolling to the bottom?

Comment: Edited my answer with a solution that shows the alert only once.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why this works in a new html but not in Framework7?

Comment: I am not sure what is Framework7. Post a new question with the details.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js"></script>

      <script>
      $(function(){
      $("#LichtStatus").on('appear',function() {
       alert("appeared");
      });
      $("#LichtStatus").on('disappear', function() {
         alert("disappeared");
      });
      $("#LichtStatus").appear();
      });

      </script>

      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/62/Incandescent_light_bulb.svg/200px-Incandescent_light_bulb.svg.png" align="center" id="LichtStatus" style="height:10vh">

  </body>
</html>
```

Check plunker for working example

https://plnkr.co/edit/YbBNxsWNFc4vP3OEBeCm

the alerts will fired once you scroll down and the image comes inside the view port and on scroll up when image leaves the viewport